# Astra Site is not importing

Tags: import

Trying to get started with my Astra Site ( Outdoor Adventure) but it has been importing for the longest time.
Is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a right place to ask the theme related questions. I'm developer of Astra. So, I recommend you to ask all your questions at https://wpastra.com/support/